# How to access/print the DNS/mDNS cache in OSX El Capitan?

Tags: network, macos, dns

I am trying to get a visual of the DNS cache (IMHO this should be extremely easy but somehow I cannot get it in El Capitan). I have tried things like:
`dscacheutil -cachedump`
which some reason returns (why?):
`Unable to get details from the cache node`
Also trying
`sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponder`
indeed printed a lot arguably useful information in `/var/log/system.log` but it does not seem to work as expected. More specifically, I searched in the log and made sure there is **no entry** for *www.my-website.com*. Then I accessed *www.my-website.com* through my web browser, re-executed `sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponder`, searched again for *www.my-website.com* in the log and once again nothing popped up (the actual search was simply "my-website" to make sure nothing was ignored). An entry didn't appear even when I used the `dig` command.

Any help why I do not see the change in the *mDNSResponder* output or where I can access the "real" DNS cache?